# FoxPro 9.0 Looping through a table

Tags: foxpro

Is it possible to loop through a table and retrieve the value from each row

```
=================
Contracts.dbf
=================
P01
C04
CH45
T31


counter = 1
Do While 1 < 4
   SomethingSomethingSomething
counter = counter + 1
ENDDO
```

So when counter = 1 the loop return P01, counter = 2 return C04 and so on.

Comment: Erm, this is a rather...vague...question.  So, you want to loop a table and return a field value?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Contracts

SCAN

    m.Counter = 1
    m.Something = ""

    DO WHILE m.Counter <= FCOUNT() 
        m.Something = EVAL(FIELD(m.Counter))
        m.Counter = m.Counter +1
    ENDDO

ENDSCAN
```

Comment: Why the EVAL? Could you flesh out your answer to explain _why_ it would work?

Comment: "loop through each row on the contracts table, then loop through each field on that row, setting the `Something` variable to each field's value before we do nothing with it, and then increment a counter of each field..."  That seems more complex than was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT contracts
SCAN
    x = contracts.fieldname1
    MESSAGEBOX("Value -> " + x)
ENDSCAN
```